# NAudio set Left and Right speakers levels through my code (Balance control)

Tags: c#, volume, naudio

I'm trying to control the volume of the left speaker and right speaker separately through my app. I'm using the library NAUDIO. At the moment i am trying to write a program that will change the master volume of the system depending on a buttons that exist in my app. off course, the windows form, but i am unable to understand how to control volume. I need it to be specific to the master volume. Is there any class to do so?

Volume mixer, Device, Speakers properties, Levels, Balance

Regards

Comment: which operating system are you using? or better: on which operation system, the app should run on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NAudio set Left and Right speakers levels through my code (Balance control)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524704/naudio-set-left-and-right-speakers-levels-through-my-code-balance-control)

Comment: @ioctlLR: That question is gone now. I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but you could do something like this...

```
MMDeviceEnumerator deviceiterator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDeviceCollection devices = deviceiterator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);

foreach(MMDevice device in devices)
{
    // Go through the devices you want to update and set your volume..
    device.EndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = 0.8f;
}
```

According to NAudio, the max volume as a scalar is 1.0f.  So setting it to 0.8f would essentially change your master control volume to 80.

Hope it helps.  I'm still trying to figure out NAudio myself so good luck :-).